# Plotting disconnects the Sage kernel on Windows 10 (unrelated to anaconda)

Tags: sage

I just installed sagemath on a Windows 10 computer, and it consistently crashes when trying to plot. I can link the origin of the code if this is relevant.

I installed Python independently and not as a bundled package like Anaconda, which is the issue in a similar question to mine.

```
F = Zmod(17)
E = EllipticCurve(F,[2,2])
plot(E) + points(((5,1), (6,3), (10,6), (3,1), (9,16), (16,13), 
                  (0,6), (13,7), (7,6), (7,11), (13,10), (0,11), 
                  (16,4), (9,1), (3,16), (10,11), (6,14), (5,16)), color='red')
```

This is the expected output:

[image]

I get the following message:

```
    The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

I tried directly calling `matplotlib` as follows:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(E)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How did you install ?  (When reading [installation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html#microsoft-windows), that seems to be the first question, and what version do you have (also which Python version?)

Comment: What is the expected output of this code (I am new to `sage`)

Comment: @Luuk I downloaded and installed from [here](https://mirrors.mit.edu/sage/win/index.html). I don't really get what "pre-built binaries for Windows based on Cygwin. This has been discontinued" means, although it is likely part the problem. I have Python 3.9.

Comment: Just running `sage` from the "SageMath 9.3 Shell" already causes a `/opt/sagemath-9.3/src/bin/sage-python: line 2:   556 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) sage -python "$@"` .....  so, I do not have clue why this script  will not do so too  

Comment: If possible, install using the Windows Subsystem for Linux. For that, follow the instructions at https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/#windows